# Redirect: How to remove certain word in all of URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to remove "/item/" in all of my urls, for example:

```
www.domain.com/it-news/item/4489
www.domain.com/software/item/4484
www.domain.com/it-news/snews/item/4480
```

should be redirect to:

```
www.domain.com/it-news/4489
www.domain.com/software/4484
www.domain.com/it-news/snews/4480
```

would you please help me to get to it
Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this `www.domain.com/item/whatever` or this `www.domain.com/it-news/snews/item` possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with .htaccess much but it seems it would go something like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/item/(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

According to [this site](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs/-httpexamplecomfolder1-to-httpexamplecomfolder2--)

Comment: I guess your rule-set fails to pass the path segment previous to `item`, like `/it-news/`.

Comment: I edited my answer, the previous answer showed how the given link showed it, I didn't think it looked right.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/item/(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
```